# Does a small 8PST switch exist?

Tags: switches

I have a POE camera that I use for streaming. It does not have a power button. So what I did was take a Neutrik Ethercon NE8FF RJ45 feedthrough coupler and simply put a 2PST slide switch on it bridging pins 7 and 8 on the RJ45 connection. Flipping the switch would disconnected the POE lines and turn off the camera.

[image]
[image]

This works GREAT for a 10/100 connection. However, I recently wired my house with 10/100/1000 lines. The thing about gigabit ethernet is that instead of POE using only 2 pins, it actually uses all 8! Which means this switch which only cuts 2 of the pins, does not kill the camera anymore.

Is there anywhere I can get an 8PST switch to cut all 8 pins? Or do I just have to accept getting two 4PST switches and flipping them both?

Comment: Clever solution. If you just want to cut data and not power, you might be okay just randomly disconnecting or some of the data wires (not power)

Answer (score 2):

While gigabit ethernet uses all 4 pairs for data, it still only uses two pairs for power in the most common PoE standards (PoE and PoE+). PoE++ is where you need to use all four pairs for the additional current that it supports. Given you're using the same camera, I don't think this is a consideration here.

You said that your current solution breaks pins 7 and 8, so it's definitely possible that your connector will still work with the new gear. Check if your switch operates using PoE Mode A or Mode B: if it uses Mode B, you're all set. Otherwise, for Mode A, you'll need to break either 1 and 2, or 3 and 6. If you have 4PST switches that fit, you could play it safe by breaking 1 and 2 and 7 and 8, which means your connector will work regardless of the PoE mode the switch uses.

Of course, standard disclaimer that adding switches like this will degrade the performance of the link since untwisting and adding components will change the characteristics of the line. If it works now, you probably don't need to worry about that though.

Sources if you want to read more:

- https://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_download/24-understanding-ieee802-3at-poeplus
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet#Pinouts